# Powershell's InvokeVerb("delete") freezes after 22H2 update

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am trying to use the powershell command for recycling file/folder.

The following script had worked for me, as a file, and called indirectly through powershell.exe by other applications.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $sh = new-object -comobject "Shell.Application"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ns = $sh.Namespace(0).ParseName("C:\New folder\test")
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ns.InvokeVerb("delete")
```

But after applying update 22H2 (the only change I've made to my computer), the command `.InvokeVerb("delete")` would be stuck frozen. There is no error code. How should I start debugging on what is wrong and then fix it?

Comment: I am on 22H2 and these statements appear to work. If the path given to ParseName() does not exist, the error message is `InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Comment: @lit: Thank you for replying. I did make sure the folder exists. I've tried empty and folder with content. Tried the usual reboot, revert update, reinstall update. Also tried standalone PS 7.4.1. None worked nor produced any error message. I wonder if it's worth mentioning them in the main body of the question.

Comment: It is always good to put what you have tried into the question.